# VB.NET : distinguished events

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling

Using VB.NET, is there anyway to distinguish an event coming from a user action and an event coming from the code?

Here is why i ask this:
I have a datagrid that users can edit and i'd like to update what they type according to cell changed detection (see code below). But as the program updates cells from the datagrid, these updates are detected as a cell changes (as exepected). Is there a way to handle differently the cell changes made from users and the cell changes made from the application itself?

```
Private Sub add_linked_obj_datagrid_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles add_linked_obj_datagrid.CellValueChanged

        Dim cellValue As String = add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value?.ToString()

        Select Case e.ColumnIndex
            Case 0
                add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = LCase(cellValue)
                Select Case cellValue
                    Case "facebook", "twitter", "instagram", "youtube", "dailymotion", "site web", "twitch", "hashtag"
                        Exit Sub
                    Case Else
                        Dim msg_error_type_interdit As String = "Le type" & cellValue & " n'est pas pris en charge."
                        MsgBox(msg_error_type_interdit, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                        add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = Nothing
                End Select
            Case 1
                add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = get_type_objet_from_value(cellValue, True)
                add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = clean_value_objet(add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value, add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value)
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe handle the `EndEdit` event instead? Or directly handle the TextBox Control in `EditingControlShowing`. Or provide a Custom Column with its own TextBox / RichTextBox control, where you can manage all the required logic internally.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use the following pattern to solve this problem:

1. Define a variable `Private m_eventLock As Integer`
2. In your methods that can trigger events, do the following

   ```
   Private Sub DoStuffThatCascasedLotsOfEvents()     
      m_eventLock += 1    
      Try

         'NORMAL LOGIC GOES HERE

      Finally
         m_eventLock -= 1
      End Try
   End Sub
   ```

(You may have more than one method that follows this patter and that is fine)

3. In you event handlers

   ```
   Private Sub myControl_MyEvent(source As Object, args As EventArgs)

      If m_eventLock > 0 Then Return

      ' THE REST OF YOUR NORMAL LOGIC

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the last advice of Jimi and used color to figure my issue out: when a row is edited by the application, its color is set to lightgreen.
It's not exactly the solution i thought but it works pretty well so far.

```
Private Sub add_linked_obj_datagrid_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles add_linked_obj_datagrid.CellValueChanged

        Dim cellValue As String = add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value?.ToString()
        If add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor <> Color.LightGreen Then
            Select Case e.ColumnIndex
                Case 0
                    add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = LCase(cellValue)
                    Select Case cellValue
                        Case "facebook", "twitter", "instagram", "youtube", "dailymotion", "site web", "twitch", "hashtag"
                            add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                        Case Else
                            Dim msg_error_type_interdit As String = "Le type" & cellValue & " n'est pas pris en charge."
                            MsgBox(msg_error_type_interdit, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                    End Select
                Case 1
                    add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = get_type_objet_from_value(cellValue, True)
                    add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = clean_value_objet(add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value, add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value)
                    add_linked_obj_datagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```